# Including subdirectories in Visual Studio 2010 Pro

Tags: visual-studio-2010, subdirectory

I am coding a project that requires me to scan through the C:. Now, I got it to scan fine, all I need is for it to include the **sub-directories** in the scan. This is as in, scanning all of the folders and the folders of the folders and so on. If anyone can get back to me, that would be great!

Comment: Post some code: how are you doing the scanning?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using .Net, you can call

```
Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"C:\", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

Comment: I am using .Net and I guess it is actually scanning the sub-directories but not the sub-directories of those sub-directories. Here's the code I am using:

Timer-1:
http://pastebin.com/naVvh5v0

Scan Button:
http://pastebin.com/qnRS508g

I am using a text file which contains MD5 signatures of viruses which are cross-scanned with the files. The problem is that it doesn't scan the folders that are inside folders (subdirectories). Please see if you can fix. I will also post a video on youtube showing the problem.

Comment: @user: You should call `Directory.EnumerateFiles` instead, as I just said.

Comment: Note that there will be too many files for a ListBox to handle.  You'll probably need to switch to virtual mode.